# how to use Push in grit using method_missing method

Tags: git, grit

I am trying to do push using grit.. however I am unable to figure out what all parameters are to be passed in rmpush.push command below.. I have already created a remote alias using git remote add and its working fine.

```
location = 'D:\GritRepo'
repo = Grit::Repo.init(location)
rmpush = Grit::Git.new(location+'\.git')
# this works fine
repo.remote_add("remoterep","https://github.com/ahmadosama/GritRepo.git")
# need help here
rmpush.Push({:repo=>'remoterep', :remote=>'master'})
```

Comment: did it using rm=rmpush.remote cmd="git push " + rm.strip + " master "
system(cmd) ... but can't pass username and password.. is there a better way to do it?

Comment: why do you use a constant, i.e. `Push`, not `push`? try using `rmpush.push...`